# when converting a list into numpy array, the numpy array does not appear to properly reflect the shape of the list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3 dimensional standard python list like this, that i convert into numpy.ndarray.

```
[[[ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 4.45436204e-02 -1.18152841e-01  5.81091651e-03  1.75189701e-01
   8.53440465e-02  2.45500185e-01 -3.86285236e-02 -1.67675946e-01
   2.10489041e-01 -7.45451800e-02 -1.73575979e-01  6.61140708e-02
   2.28021467e-01  2.35175579e-02  1.08195608e-01  6.98243782e-02
  -3.11620382e-01 -5.28595379e-02 -3.04707440e-02 -1.46316723e-01
  -1.63287363e-02  7.38108413e-02 -4.02233925e-02 -2.58813309e-01
   2.86307108e-01  1.84222449e-02 -8.73278690e-02  1.34181943e-01
   1.31953371e-01 -8.60154436e-02  1.00176111e-01  5.97644780e-02
  -1.83773632e-01  1.37019054e-01  3.77848040e-01 -2.45231941e-01
   1.19619185e-01 -1.80678744e-01 -1.32710775e-01 -8.28977111e-02
   3.10254213e-02  1.40633371e-02 -6.30242416e-02  2.71421439e-03
  -4.01602220e-02  1.02678916e-01 -7.31588416e-03  1.00152795e-01
   7.26195492e-02 -1.47529329e-02]
 [-1.70314188e-02 -1.69005796e-01 -8.28800462e-02 -2.11857884e-01
   2.63179751e-01  1.00920919e-01 -8.69913485e-02 -3.11308872e-04
   2.23594335e-01 -4.37707223e-02 -1.34373199e-01 -1.27122122e-01
   1.53113785e-01  1.79207915e-01 -1.22818809e-03  1.02410680e-01
   1.96340445e-01  1.10872969e-01  1.54811636e-01 -2.85541897e-03
  -9.43836549e-02  5.48555974e-02  9.70891710e-02 -3.40892820e-01
   3.54860214e-01  2.50265744e-02 -1.39156182e-01 -1.47769722e-01
  -6.81893380e-03  9.77047716e-02  4.27919221e-02  1.26990833e-01
   8.33452299e-02  9.02411794e-03  1.68550777e-01 -8.78511732e-02
  -3.02674808e-02 -1.70726882e-01 -3.40348605e-02  2.03117528e-01
   1.71536812e-01  1.71283012e-01 -1.56022182e-01  1.79780594e-01
   4.93034571e-02  1.33902594e-01  7.43260075e-02  9.69842396e-02
   7.61786160e-02  1.93897780e-02]
 [-9.30330154e-02  2.58336350e-01  2.14432592e-01 -3.40601467e-02
  -2.90417098e-02  1.59327676e-02 -1.53500335e-02 -3.07211392e-02
  -1.78522124e-01  1.34527918e-01 -1.85403253e-02  2.75971014e-01
   6.20661118e-02  4.11185578e-02  1.24071234e-01 -4.00851500e-02
  -1.29755038e-01 -1.13966083e-01 -2.92663395e-01  2.93868568e-01
   8.74598053e-02 -1.91889755e-01 -7.14387025e-02  2.25763608e-01
  -5.11298667e-02  2.46037768e-01  4.99689186e-02  8.93151437e-02
   6.48412926e-02  1.28423153e-01 -7.55411755e-02 -3.35367547e-02
  -1.00356044e-01 -1.88139411e-02 -1.51477720e-01  1.65922431e-02
   7.96821939e-02  1.42692675e-01 -2.18531805e-01  4.97433868e-02
  -9.04071330e-03  1.38911819e-01  4.93340506e-02  7.97865258e-02
  -9.59501597e-02  6.75884324e-02 -1.79584439e-01  4.84889612e-02
  -3.21113524e-01 -1.79968880e-01]
 [-2.41284266e-01  7.97963761e-02  1.86475801e-01  1.89798208e-01
  -2.77824217e-03  3.94232665e-02  4.02033206e-02 -1.24912462e-01
  -5.74203563e-02  1.12372037e-01 -1.52237674e-01 -2.25086598e-02
  -2.77266567e-01 -1.30789305e-01  6.49656680e-02 -3.39610499e-01
   2.53307957e-02 -1.22250725e-01 -1.75178017e-01  9.83586325e-02
   9.20468207e-02 -2.16074809e-01 -6.97953706e-02  5.68807664e-02
  -8.16337060e-02  1.32941545e-02 -1.08594468e-01  4.00146746e-03
  -1.00481417e-01 -8.83162216e-02  3.44004949e-01  6.98876313e-02
  -9.17468147e-02 -2.90163677e-01 -1.53225965e-01 -1.34154931e-02
  -7.04675300e-02  9.54190201e-02 -7.27025599e-02  5.43151452e-02
   1.35024206e-01  2.68047090e-01 -1.61011721e-01  1.95309601e-01
   9.52259311e-02  2.98724401e-03 -8.44182808e-02 -2.22204450e-02
   2.12424195e-02 -6.18712319e-02]]]
```

The list I am converting is a list of lists of lists of 50 floats each (they represent sentences made up of word vectors). I would expect the shape of the resulting numpy array to be `(len(list), len(line_in_list), len(vector_in_line))`. So for this exact example I expect the shape to be (1, 9, 50). However, using `numpy.asarray(list)` and then printing `list.shape`, the output is `(1,)` I am sure I am making a stupid mistake but I cant seem to find a solution anywhere. My goal is to prepare this data for input to an RNN so i have to arrange the data into the correct shape first. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Separate the lists with commas ?
+
np.array instead of np.asarray

Comment: They are, I just copy and pasted that list from the terminal to show you guys and the print doesnt show commas

Comment: I found the solution, I had forgotten to convert the lists that held the actual vectors to numpy arrays